# Unable to encode element with coder 'AvroCoder'

Tags: java, encode, avro, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In GCP Dataflow I am returning a `PCollection` of following class from a `DoFn`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.avro.reflect.Nullable;

import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.DefaultCoder;
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public class MyClass{
  @Nullable
  public String id;
  @Nullable
  public String foo;
  @Nullable
  public List<Integer> foo2;
  @Nullable
  public Map<String,List<String>> foo3;
  @Nullable
  public List<String> foo4;
}
```

Getting error:

> Unable to encode element MyClass with coder 'AvroCoder'.

[Full Strack Trace](https://pastebin.com/2zQufAMh)

The root cause looks to be this portion of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
  java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
  at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:78)
```

My `DoFn` function returns above class's instances in a HashMap, like below:

```
 public static class Prep extends DoFn<TableRow, KV<String, MyClass>> {
}
```

Comment: Is there more to the error message? The stack trace and complete error would be helpful.

Comment: @BenChambers full stack trace is here https://pastebin.com/2zQufAMh

Comment: Can you reproduce using the DirectRunner? It would allow you to set a breakpoint around these errors, and then identifying exactly what field in the class is causing problems and inspect the value that is problematic. It suggests that either the Avro schema doesn't match the actual data, or that something within the data is incorrect.